# Using a dropdown list to filter a table (dataTables)

Tags: jquery, filter, drop-down-menu, datatables

I'm using the dataTables jQuery plugin (which is totally awesome), but I'm having trouble getting my table to filter based on the change of my select box.

Function:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#msds-table").dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": false
       });

      var oTable;
      oTable = $('#msds-table').dataTable();

      $('#msds-select').change( function() { 
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() ); 
       });
   });
```

HTML:

```
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="msds-table">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Column 1</th>
                        <th>Column 2</th>
                        <th>etc</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <select id="#msds-select">
                    <option>All</option>
                    <option>Group 1</option>
                    <option>Group 2</option>
                    <option>Group 3</option>
                    <option>Group 4</option>
                    <option>Group 5</option>
                    <option>Group 6</option>
                    </select>
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td>Group 1</td>
                        <td><img src="images/modules/download-icon.gif" width="12" height="17" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><a href="#">Download</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="even">
                        <td>Group 1</td>
                        <td><img src="images/modules/download-icon.gif" width="12" height="17" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><a href="#">Download</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd">
                        <td>Group 1</td>
                        <td><img src="images/modules/download-icon.gif" width="12" height="17" alt="" /></td>
                        <td><a href="#">Download</a></td>
                    </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Table goes on to display a bunch of items, up to "Group 6", but you get the idea.
Anyone ever tried to do this before?

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about what your actual problem is? Or could you post some code of what you have attempted and what isn't working for you?

Comment: Return key fail. Updated w/ code.

Comment: It took me about a week to get this working for me.  I wish I still had access to the source I used.  Fundamentally, there was a problem in the source code for it which I had to go in and change.  Unfortunately, the website for datatables wasn't too descriptive when it came to this functionality.  I would check their forums, I posted about it a few times there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[dataTables features](http://www.datatables.net/usage/features)

I knew I had done this before, and you have to watch this little piece of information:

> Note that if you wish to use filtering in DataTables this must remain
>   'true' - to remove the default filtering input box and retain
>   filtering abilities, please use 
>   [sDom](http://www.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom).

you need to set {bFilter:true}, and move your `<select></select>` into a custom element registered through sDom. I can guess your code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#msds-table").dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bFilter": true,
        "sDom":"lrtip" // default is lfrtip, where the f is the filter
       });
      var oTable;
      oTable = $('#msds-table').dataTable();

      $('#msds-select').change( function() { 
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() ); 
       });
   });
```

your code for `oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() );` will not fire while `{bFilter:false};` according to the documentation

Comment: Ah, the filter makes sense, but I still can't get it to fire; It's got to be something with the sDom no? The documentation on it isn't to clear.

Comment: Ok, just read up on the sDom. Your code should totally work! No dice though. The only other thing I can think of is where in the HTML the <select> is located?

Comment: Wow, just looked at my select id=#msds-select...I'm attributing that one to Friday evening fried brain. Thanks for your help, cheers.

Comment: glad i could help ;)  . that filtering tidbit caught me the first time through, and sucked to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            "bFilter": true,
                initComplete: function () {
                    this.api().column(1).every( function () {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $('<select><option value="">All Subjects</option></select>')
                            .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                            .on( 'change', function () {
                                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                                column
                                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                    .draw();
                            } );
                        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                        } );
                    } );
                },
        } );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
 $('.btn-success').on('click',function (e) {
               //to prevent the form from submitting use e.preventDefault()
                e.preventDefault();
                var res = $("#userid").val();  
                var  sNewSource = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>myaccount/MyData_select?userid=" + res + "";
                var oSettings = ETable.fnSettings();
                oSettings.sAjaxSource  = sNewSource;
                ETable.fnDraw();
            });
```