# in codeigniter using datatables how to show dropdown filter for required column

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatables

I want to filter the list using datatables dropdown list on required column like city

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sl.no</th>
            <th>Principle</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Branch Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $i=1; foreach($branchDetails as $branch) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $branch->principle_name;?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $branch->city_name;?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $branch->branchName;?></td>
            <td class="center">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/Branch/edit/<?php echo $branch->branchId ; ?>">
                    <i class="icon-edit"></i>  
                </a>
                <!--<a href="#" data-id="<?php echo $branch->branchId;?>">
                    <i class="icon-trash"></i> 
                </a>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

datatables js is

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
            }
        } );
```

how can i implement to show drop downfilter on this .

Comment: Follow these links, it may solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046308/using-a-dropdown-list-to-filter-a-table-datatables

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494355/filter-table-data-based-on-drop-down-values-of-first-column-only-in-datatables

Answer (score 2):

> I think you read this tutorial might be you can get it

[Click Here For Multi Dropdown Filter](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have only selected columns dropdown filter.It can be achieved

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            if(column[0]==1){ /* is the second column you want to have dropdown filter */
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            }
        } );
    }
} );
} );
```

[Working example in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3dkNz6GwyJDAvbLu9ImJ?p=preview)

Comment: I used this but i got error:DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

Comment: This was already initialized in footer but i want in only one list.

Comment: @vijay kumar  if you want only one list that is city in your case . so  you should use `if(column[0]==2){` to have city drop down only. you should see plunker link how it is done